# adding elements to scrollview using java when there is more then 1 child

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I am trying to add elements to my scrollview,
this scroll view has a vertical linear layout inside of it.
(i added another linear layout - horizontl, inside that will manage 2 textviews and an image according to the attributes i assigned them),

i am trying to add elements of this inner layout to my scroll view (id=insideLineLayout)
(each element added to scrollview will contain these 2 texts and an image)
because of the fact scrollview can only have 1 child i am unable to do this.
would appreciate some help, nothing seems to be working here.
Thanks.

my current xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/searchScreenOuterLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
         >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/catagoryselectedText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:text="selected catagory"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/searchText"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/searchButton"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/search_icon" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/radiusText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="Search Radius"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/radiusBar"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>





    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/searchScrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/searchScrollViewLinear"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/insideLineLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="100"
                 >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/linesPrice"
                    android:layout_weight="20"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="tmp1"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/linesInfo"
                     android:layout_weight="60"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp" 
                    android:text="tmp2"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageInfo"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/tv_icon" />

            </LinearLayout>





        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can make multiple copies of `insideLineLayout` and add them to `searchScrollViewLinear`. But this seems a lot like a ListView...

Comment: adding these should be done dynamically, since i won't know how many elements will be added, and their information until i get them. (otherwise you are right, and i'd do what you suggested)

Comment: @Roy what's the issue? Programmatically adding views to the LinearLayout inside the ScrollView results in an error? +1 to Sam.

Answer (score 0):

Consider how long your list can get as `ListView` has been optimized in many ways which a regular scroll view is not. If you have too many elements you might start get out of memory exceptions.

In order to dynamically add views to a `ScrollView` you first need to get the container view inside the `ScrollView` (most likely a `LinearLayout`), then you simply do following for each view you add:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_to_add, container, false); // this is used if you create from xml, if you make it in code you'd use the regular constructor.
// update the view content (view.findViewById(); etc.)
container.addView(view);
```